# Is there a bug with PostbackUrl and URL Rewriting?

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I have a page where I set the PostBackUrl property on a login button. I am using the IIS7 Url Rewriting Module. I am also rewriting the Page.Form.Action attribute to match the rewritten url, so that postbacks work properly. When I have the PostBackUrl property set, the page adds a "__PREVIOUSPAGE" hidden input. The problem is that ALL postbacks are now broken, such that the request is seen as a new request, and Page.IsPostback == false. Removing the line of code that sets PostBackUrl fixes all my postback issues.

I don't think I can rewrite the encrypted __PREVIOUSPAGE value to match the current rewritten url, but I suspect that is the issue. Has anyone else encountered and solved this problem?

Answer (score -1):

ASP.NET webforms and url rewriting have never played particularly well. You might want to look at routing, which will work loads better . . .

Comment: I'm a little far down the rabbit hole to switch to MVC

Comment: Fair enough, but I'm also probably not switching to routing just to fix this issue. Really this is the only problem I have run into with Url Rewriting.